# How to maintain session and timeout redirects in React JS with an Express Backend?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, express-session

I am using react to develop an application (not native) which has a login/logout system. I used to implement Redux-persist and persist my state to my localStorage. This system was used for client side authentication. It had a JSON object of name, email, jwt-token and a isAuthenticated(boolean). I never liked this implementation cause of security concerns. So a bit of research got me to express-session with redis-store. I inspected websites like Instagram and other react based sites, they have nothing vital stored on localStorage, sessionStorage but they do have a 'session' cookie which is an encrypted string of user data. What confuses me is this 'session' cookie is what is used for server side authentication cause once I clear the cookie and reload the page I get logged out. But how do you do the client side authentication when nothing is persisted on the client side? With React and Express backend is there any other way to do this or can someone explain me this system?

Comment: don't want to start explaining in depth how it works but yeah you should not store authentication related stuff in client side all you need is the cookie, as soon as user is logged out or session expired reset the redux state on client side so the user gets classic login screen even if the user "fakes" the state and gets to an page that he shouldn't be force resetting - since there no cookie the server can't consider the user as logged in.

Comment: @Gntem Thank you for the comment. So this is how I am planning to do it. Express-session with redis-store, store a cookie with vital data which will be sent to the server on every request. Regarding redux state how do I persist it?

Comment: You can add a set-cookie header along with the response which will be handled by the browser to set the cookie for this session and send this cookie along with all your api calls

Comment: yes express-session with redis-store would come extra benefits etc its a good start. If you are not building an single page application you can use local storage, if you build an single page app with react router/redux etc you don't need to store it anywhere. Don't store too much in the cookie except locale and session id

Comment: @RohithMurali Thank you. I got that point. But what about client side authentication? If it's redux then how to I persist it? And how do I logout when page is been reloaded cause it's a react app not normal html css which uses express for routing. React uses it's own router.

Comment: @Gntem this is not a single page application. I have various routes and components. I am developing a dashboard. So localStorage and if it is cleared then I should log the user out?

Comment: @Gntem also how do I handle reloads if session cookie is cleared by user? Since react has its own routing and doesn't depend on express

Comment: react doesn't have any concept of routing whatsoever .. IF you are using react router you can probably check if the user is authorised to access the route .. either way try reading more about react-router , react , express etc you are mixing a lot of stuff and it doesn't seem that you know the basics start from that..